# How to delete rows of a dataframe where values are within a range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The first column of my dataframe (df) is score. I want to delete rows with score >20 & <50.

I am using the following code in order to do it:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.score < 50) & (df.score > 20)].index)
```

But I want to delete the rows making reference to the column number and not the column name:

This code is not working:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.columns[0] < 50) & (df.columns[0] > 20)].index)
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be `df.column.values[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straightforward, using `loc/iloc`:

```
v = df.iloc[:, 0]  # v = df.loc[:, df.columns[0]]
df = df[~((v > 20) & (v < 50))]
```

A cleaner approach using `pd.Series.between`:

```
df = df[~df.iloc[:, 0].between(20, 50, inclusive=False)]
```